# How to make a zip file containing two folders inside in laravel using Chumper/Zipper?

Tags: laravel, zip

In my program two type of members can add images to the database and locally.
There is a download function which will download all images (which were added by both members) as a zip file.

I need to make a zip file which contain two folders for both members using Chumper/Zipper in laravel. When I download the zip file it should contain two folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution as following

```
        Zipper::make('uploads/staff/'.$order->bucket_name.'.zip')
                ->folder('Retouch_files')->add($file_retouch)
                ->folder('Cad_files')->add($file_cad)
                ->close();
```

By using '->folder('folder_name')->add(file_you_want_to_add_inside)'  we can create any amount of folders.